# Retrieving file names from libssh2_sftp_readdir_ex()

Tags: c++, sftp, libssh2

I am working on a C++ code that I need to list all files and directories in a path by using the `libssh2_sftp_readdir_ex()` function of LIBSSH2.

However, I tried to run the example (`sftpdir.c`) and I noticed that the code prints all files and directories along with stats, permissions and etc and I am looking for way to print only file and directories names.

Basically, I am trying get the file names from an vector of strings in C++ that contains the output generated by the `libssh2_sftp_readdir_ex()` command. The entries look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 sftpuser sftpgroup      318 Sep 29 13:33 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root           36 Aug  6 22:18 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users         607 Aug  9 17:48 sample1.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users     1311881 Aug  9 17:48 sample1.docx
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users       29380 Aug  9 17:48 sample1.xlsx
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users      120515 Aug  9 17:48 sample2.docx
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users       32924 Aug  9 17:48 sample2.xlsx
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users       34375 Aug  9 17:49 sample3.docx
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users        3541 Aug  9 17:49 sample3.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users       13246 Aug  9 17:49 sample3.xlsx
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users    14169117 Aug  9 17:49 sample4.docx
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users     2069007 Aug  9 17:49 sample_1280×853.png
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users     4767276 Aug  9 17:49 sample_1920×1280.png
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users    35898398 Aug  9 17:49 sample_5184×3456.png
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users      534283 Aug  9 17:49 sample_640×426.png
-rw-r--r--    1 sftpuser users          20 Aug 31 18:56 testedown.txt
```

Currently I have implemented this code below that should parse each string in an vector (`LSEntriesFull`) to an another vector (`LSEntriesBrief`) that get only the file names:

```
const std::regex separator("\\s+");

// Each element of LSEntriesFull we need to do the parsing
for (auto & it : LSEntriesFull) {
    std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> itr(it.begin(), it.end(), separator, -1);
    std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> end;

    while (itr != end) {
        // Lets print to stderr to check if its ok
        std::cerr << " [" << *itr++ << "]";
        // TODO: Filter in an optimal way only the file names
        LSEntriesBrief.emplace_back(*itr++);    // WRONG!!! It is getting all elements
    }
}
```

What is the best optimal way to do this parsing in order to get only the filenames from the vector (`LSEntriesFull`) and to put into the other vector (`LSEntriesBrief`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libssh2_sftp_readdir_ex` gives you the filename via the `buffer` parameter. There's no need to parse the `longentry`.

It's indeed not really clear from the documentation.

---

You should not try to parse the `longentry` for any other reason. As the libssh2 documentation say:

> The format of the `longname' field is unspecified by SFTP protocol.

The `longentry` is for display only (to be "parsed" by the human reader).

Check the [libssh2 `sftpdir.c` example](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/master/example/sftpdir.c). When the `libssh2_sftp_readdir_ex` returns any `longdesc`, the example code prints it *as it is*. When not, it assembles display information from `buffer` (`mem` in the example) and the `attrs` (`LIBSSH2_SFTP_ATTRIBUTES`).

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. :D